# List comprehension works in Python shell, but not inside a script

Tags: python

I'm writing a math plugin for a bot, and testing my code in the python interactive shell which executes it normally:

```
>>> text = "!math 0.023*67"

>>> string1 = [b for b in a for a in text.split("!math ") if len(a) != 0]

>>> print string1

['0', '.', '0', '2', '3', '*', '6', '7']
```

But when i include it in a script, it fails with a TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/ema/Openshift/pythonbot/plugins/math/math.py", line 61, in <module>
string1 = [b for b in a for a in text.split("!math ") if len(a) != 0]
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: So what is `a` set to when you run your first piece? It can only succeed if you have it defined to be an iterable *first*. In your case, it must've been set to `'0.023*67'` for your given output.

Comment: Indeed. I can't find it on my console but usually before trying list comprehension i write a regular for loop first, so that must be when a was set to that value. Anyways, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your posted code doesn't work either. Do `del a` in your interactive interpreter and try to run it again. You'll see it fail:

```
>>> text = "!math 0.023*67"
>>> [b for b in a for a in text.split("!math ") if len(a) != 0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

You have the order of your loops mixed up. List them in *nesting order* from left to right:

```
[b for a in text.split("!math ") if len(a) != 0 for b in a]
```

This now works without `a` being defined up front:

```
>>> a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
>>> text = "!math 0.023*67"
>>> [b for a in text.split("!math ") if len(a) != 0 for b in a]
['0', '.', '0', '2', '3', '*', '6', '7']
```